# How to insert in a table and display the table content on Apache server?

Tags: java, mysql

I have database **studentdb** and table name **student** in MySQL. what should i do in order to insert the data and fetch complete table from the database. username is "**root**" and password is also "**root**".

I want to insert data in table and after that I want to display the table data content.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        try{

        //loading drivers for mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //creating connection with the database 
          Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
                     ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb","root","root");

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
                  ("insert into Student values(?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, email);
        ps.setString(3, pass);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();

          if(i>0)
          {
            out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
          }
          String query = "SELECT * FROM student";

      // create the java statement
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();

      // execute the query, and get a java resultset
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

      // iterate through the java resultset
      while (rs.next())
      {
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        String email = rs.getString("email");
        String password = rs.getString("pass");


        // print the results
        System.out.format("%s, %s, %s\n", name, email, password);
      }
      st.close();

        }
        catch(Exception se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());

      }
  }`enter code here`
```

There are 3 columns in database "name", "email", "pass".

Comment: none of lines has to do with http, so what can have to '404' ?

Comment: Sorry, i did copy the wrong code, Now i have updated with new one.